# How to properly synchronous threads in pthreads?

Tags: c++, operating-system, pthreads, semaphore

I am implementing a producer-consumer problem using pthreads and semaphore. I have 1 Producer and 2 Consumers. My Producer reads characters one by one from a file and enqueues them into a circular queue. I want the consumers to read from the queue and store into separate arrays. I want the reading in such a way that the first consumer reads 2 characters and the second consumer reads every 3rd character. I am trying to do this using `pthread_cond_wait()` but it is not working out. This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<queue>
#include "circular_queue"

// define queue size
#define QUEUE_SIZE 5

// declare and initialize semaphore and read/write counter
static sem_t mutex,queueEmptyMutex;
//static int counter = 0;

// Queue for saving characters
static Queue charQueue(QUEUE_SIZE);
//static std::queue<char> charQueue;

// indicator for end of file
static bool endOfFile = false;

// save arrays
static char consumerArray1[100];
static char consumerArray2[100];

static pthread_cond_t cond;
static pthread_mutex_t cond_mutex; 
static bool thirdCharToRead = false;

void *Producer(void *ptr)
{
    int i=0;
    std::ifstream input("string.txt");
    char temp;
    while(input>>temp)
    {
        std::cout<<"reached here a"<<std::endl;
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        std::cout<<"reached here b"<<std::endl;
        if(!charQueue.full())
        {
            charQueue.enQueue(temp);
        }
        sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);
        sem_post(&mutex);

        i++;

        sleep(4);
    }

    endOfFile = true;
    sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void *Consumer1(void *ptr)
{

    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&queueEmptyMutex);
    bool loopCond = endOfFile;
    while(!loopCond)
    {
        std::cout<<"consumer 1 loop"<<std::endl;
        if(endOfFile)
        {

            loopCond = charQueue.empty();
            std::cout<<loopCond<<std::endl;
            sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);
        }
       sem_wait(&queueEmptyMutex);


        sem_wait(&mutex);


        if(!charQueue.empty())
        {

            consumerArray1[i] = charQueue.deQueue();
            i++;
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);
                std::cout<<"Signal cond. i = "<<i<<std::endl;
                thirdCharToRead = true;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);
                pthread_cond_signal(&cond);

            }
        }        
        if(charQueue.empty()&&endOfFile)
        {

            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);

            break;
        }  
        sem_post(&mutex);

        sleep(2);
        std::cout<<"consumer 1 loop end"<<std::endl;
    }

    consumerArray1[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void *Consumer2(void *ptr)
{

    int i = 0;
    sem_wait(&queueEmptyMutex);
    bool loopCond = endOfFile;
    while(!loopCond)
    {
        std::cout<<"consumer 2 loop"<<std::endl;
        if(endOfFile)
        {

            loopCond = charQueue.empty();
            std::cout<<loopCond<<std::endl;
            sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);
        }
        sem_wait(&queueEmptyMutex);


        sem_wait(&mutex);


        if(!charQueue.empty())
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);

            while(!thirdCharToRead)
            {
                std::cout<<"Waiting for condition"<<std::endl;
                pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&cond_mutex);
            }
            std::cout<<"Wait over"<<std::endl;
            thirdCharToRead = false;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);

            consumerArray2[i] = charQueue.deQueue();

            i++;
        }  
        if(charQueue.empty()&& endOfFile)
        {
            sem_post(&mutex);
            sem_post(&queueEmptyMutex);
            break;
        }  

        sem_post(&mutex);
        std::cout<<"consumer 2 loop end"<<std::endl;
        sleep(2);

    }

    consumerArray2[i] = '\0';
    pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);
    sem_init(&queueEmptyMutex,0,1);
    pthread_mutex_init(&cond_mutex,NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&cond,NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread[0],NULL,Producer,NULL);
    int rc = pthread_create(&thread[1],NULL,Consumer1,NULL);
    if(rc)
    {
        std::cout<<"Thread not created"<<std::endl;
    }
    pthread_create(&thread[2],NULL,Consumer2,NULL);
    pthread_join(thread[0],NULL);pthread_join(thread[1],NULL);pthread_join(thread[2],NULL);
    std::cout<<"First array: "<<consumerArray1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Second array: "<<consumerArray2<<std::endl;
    sem_destroy(&mutex);
    sem_destroy(&queueEmptyMutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The problem I am having is after one read, consumer 2 goes into infinite loop in the `while(!thirdCharToRead)`. Is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: Any reason to use PThreads over [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread)? You probably also want to use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of raw C-style character buffers.

Comment: You should also get out of the habit of jamming a bunch of lines together in one line for no reason. It impairs readability. That one convoluted line could be a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @tadman I am supposed to use pthread

Comment: @tadman which line? can you please specify?

Comment: You have a pile of `pthread_join` statements in `main`. Consider using `std::vector<pthread> threads` and later you can `for (auto& thread : threads)` to iterate over them and do whatever you need. C-style arrays can be largely avoided in C++. I hope you're using a modern version of C++ and not some museum grace implementation.

Comment: @tadman actually I am not allowed to use any C++ libraries.

Comment: Is this for a C++ course of some kind? Having the Standard Library off limits is preposterous.

Comment: @tadman its actually operating system college course assignment. but I have to learn the coding part of pthreads all my myself.

Comment: @tadman well what can you tell me about the condition problem?

Comment: That adds some important context. It's worth mentioning any unusual constraints you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's start with this code:

```
        std::cout<<"Wait over"<<std::endl;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&cond_mutex);
        thirdCharToRead = false;
```

This code says that `cond_mutex` does not protect `thirdCharToRead` from concurrent access. Why? Because it modifies `thirdCharToRead` without holding that mutex.

Now look at this code:

```
        pthread_mutex_lock(&cond_mutex);

        while(!thirdCharToRead)
        {
            std::cout<<"Waiting for condition"<<std::endl;
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&cond_mutex);
        }
```

Now, the `while` loop checks `thirdCharToRead`, so we must hold whatever lock protects `thirdCharToRead` from concurrent access when we test it. But the `while` loop will loop forever if `thirdCharToRead` stays locked for the whole loop since no other thread could ever change it. Thus, this code only makes sense if somewhere in the loop we release the lock that protects `thirdCharToRead`, and the only lock we release in the loop is `cond_mutex` in the call to `pthread_cond_wait`.

So this code only makes sense if `cond_mutex` protects `thirdCharToRead`.

Houston, we have a problem. One chunk of code says `cond_mutex` does not protect `thirdCharToRead` and one chunk of code says `cond_mutex` does protect `thirdCharToRead`.

Comment: I changed that but now the code is getting stuck in the producer `sem_wait(&mutex)` part. the output is as follows: consumer 1 loop
reached here a
reached here b
consumer 2 loop
reached here a
reached here b
consumer 1 loop end
consumer 1 loop
reached here a
reached here b
reached here a and then its stuck there

Comment: Your `if(!charQueue.empty())` block always locks a mutex and only sometimes unlocks it.

Comment: Here's a thought: The only thing that you need to protect against concurrent access is the queue and the only other thing you need is some way for the consumer to wait for the queue to become non-empty. So ditch the semaphores. Use one mutex to protect the queue and one condition variable to wait for the queue to be non-empty.

Comment: I fixed that as well, still same output. also I am not checking whether queue empty with condition. i want to check that consumer 2 is reading every 3rd character and consumer 1 reads every other 2.eg: string.txt has 'abcdefgh', consumer 1 must read 'abdegh' and consumer 2 must read 'cf'

Comment: @ShantanuShinde You can still use just a condition variable and a mutex. The mutex protects all shared state and the condition variable is broadcast any time the shared state changes in a way that might allow a thread to make forward progress.

Comment: but my assignment says to use semaphore for queue protection. also what do you suggest on the solution to the question I have put. how do I  make consumer 2 read every third char?

Comment: You can't use a semaphore for queue protection and also use a condition variable because a cv's atomic "unlock and wait" semantic can only unlock a mutex. You'll have to go back to the earlier design with two semaphores, one to protect the queue and one to wait on.

Comment: I edited the code and now it is working. will you edit it into your answer so I  can accept it as answer? I will post it as my own answer, you put it in one answer. is that ok?